# Google OAuth running on remote server and authenticating locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth

I'm using Python to interact with Google Sheet API using a library called [gspread_pandas](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

The flow to let this python script to authenticate on google is basically:

- Create a project on GCP;
- Create an OAuth2 token (the application type is "web app" , but in doubt if should be
  "desktop app");
- Expose the token on local environment and run the python script;
- The Python Script will ask to access a link like below:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=foo.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8182%2F&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets&state=acbdef&access_type=offline
```

- And if I succeed on login, it runs the script smoothly (the data from sheets are retrieved by the python script).

[Link to the description of authentication process.](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#authentication)

It runs fine if I'm running it locally on my machine, when I setup this workflow on EC2,
when I run the python script on the EC2 terminal, it asks me to access an external link (accounts.google...) and when I click on it, I open the browser on my local machine, I insert my google credentials and at the end of the process it throws:

```
    This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
    Try:
    
    Checking the connection
    Checking the proxy and the firewall
    ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The terminal on EC2 keeps stuck waiting for the login process to end but it already failed on my local browser (on my machine).
My suspicion is that when I log on google using my local browser, it can't get back to the EC2 and finish the authentication process.

The type of this OAuth token is "Web Application" and the URI redirect I set `https://<public-ip>.sslip.io/8182` (so I can use the aws public ip on gcp, for testing only).

I wonder how to use Google OAuth on a remove server and login to google account on my local browser. I'm trying this method because the library docs says its possible:

> you will have to authenticate through a text based OAuth prompt; this makes it possible to run on a headless server through ssh or through a Jupyter notebook

[Link to citation](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#authentication)

I tried to use service-account but my company does not allow this kind of auth.